# Drag Up A new view in iOS

Tags: ios, webview, draggable, uipangesturerecognizer

I wanted to know how I could grab a button from the bottom of my app and when i click, and flick it up, a webview thats underneath that button apears with the button now on the top of the screen, then when the user is done with the webview they can flick it back down to show the main menu?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a gesture recogniser to the button and handle its action to animate the button and the view. Depending on exactly the gesture and effect you want you may want to create your own gesture subclass and / or add the gesture to the buttons superview instead of the button itself.

Note for the future, with iOS 7 dragging from the bottom of the screen is handled by the OS so don't make your gesture too similar...